# The Rails way to change URL based on variable? Routing and perhaps namespace related

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

I have an `images` table with a `nsfw` flag.

What's the best way to add `nsfw` and `sfw` to the URL?

For example,

if I have an image with an id=1 and nsfw flag is true, I want the URL to be `/images/nsfw/1`

if I have an image with an id=2 and nsfw flag is false, I want the URL to be `/images/sfw/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named routes will do what you want.

```
map.sfw '/images/sfw/:id', :action => 'show' , :controller => 'images', :params => {:nsfw => false}
map.nsfw '/images/nsfw/:id', :action => 'show' , :controller => 'images', :params => {:nsfw => true}
```

This will provide handy methods for link_to and route correctly. setting the :nsfw value in the params hash accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with routes:

```
map.connect ':controller/images/:nsfw/:id', :action => 'show', :nsfw => /n?sfw/
```

You then can check the nsfw values (which will be 'nsfw' or 'sfw') the same way you get :id.

Comment: Is there an argument that I can pass to `map.resources :images` so that when I <%= link_to 'image', image %> it will create the correct n?sfw link?